# Reshaping big dataset with MinMaxScaler giving error

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

My data set is of shape `(1249, 228)`. Most of the entries are zero and other are integers like 1,2,5,10,20 etc. I want to transform this set for the input into LSTM. But when I am applying `MinMaxScaler`. It is giving the following error:

## load the dataset:

```
dataset1 = pd.read_csv('g:/hello.csv', engine='python')
dataset1= dataset1.drop('packages', axis=1)
dataset1 = dataset1.astype('float32')
```

## normalizing the set

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset1 = scaler.fit_transform(dataset1)
```

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

How can I transform this data set according to the input in LSTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you checked for NaN and Inf values manually.

According to the solutions posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44869902/6204860 and
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/11933/52089

if dataset1 is a Pandas `DataFrame` try converting it to a matrix by running [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html):

```
dataset1 = dataset1.as_matrix().astype(np.float)
np.nan_to_num(dataset1)
```

and then run `dataset1 = scaler.fit_transform(dataset1)`.

Let me know if this works :)