# train_test_split ValueError: Input contains NaN

Tags: python, sampling

I tried to do a stratified sampling by way of `train_test_split` in order to save myself some trouble later. So I wrote the following lines:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X=data_df
y=data_df.pop('class')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.125, stratify=y)
```

I got the error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Some helpful suggestions: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32)

Comment: Here the specific peculiarity is that `train_test_split` doesn't care about missing values, _except_ that OP is stratifying on `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any null or `nan` values:

```
X[X.isnull() == True]
```

Then you have to decide what to do with those `nan` values. Something that is commonly done is to forward fill in place.

```
X.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
y.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
```

Comment: `train_test_split` shouldn't care whether `X` has missing values.  And I wouldn't suggest using forward-fill unless you have some reason to believe that's a reasonable imputation method.  (And it will still fail to fill all missings if they happen to appear first.)

Comment: maybe the 'y' has null values and that's the problem because of stratification on 'y'

Answer (score 0):

(Upgrading comment to answer.)

This error message is generally pretty straightforward: you have missing values (generally one of `np.nan`, `pd.NA`, `None`), and whatever method you're trying to use cannot handle that.

Now `train_test_split` doesn't usually care about missing values: it's just splitting up the rows, so why should it care what values are in there?  *But*, in this case you're asking to `stratify` on `y` (making the train/test split have the same proportion of each class in `y`), and so it does care about the values in `y`.  So the error is because you have missing values in `y`.

Missing the target variable is problematic.  The best thing to do is probably to drop those rows, unless there's some additional context (e.g. if your data is time-series, maybe you can impute based on the adjacent rows).