# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nan_to_num'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, random-forest, numpy

I'm trying to run a Random Forest model from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) but I keep getting an error: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').`

I tried following steps in [ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32)

`fillna(0)` on my pandas dataframe still gave the ValueError.

So I tried working with my numpy array:

```
val = setTo.ravel().nan_to_num(0)
```

But I keep getting an error: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nan_to_num'`

I'm wondering how I can deal with the nan values if I have ndarray?

#### Update

Thanks so much to @Beniamin H for all the help, as suggested, I rescaled the data, which I based on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771118/sklearn-random-forest-error-on-input and it worked!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Data Science Stack Exchange :)

Comment: Thanks so much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right method but in a wrong way :)

[`nan_to_num`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) is a method of `numpy` module, not `numpy.ndarray`. So instead of calling `nan_to_num` on you data, call it on numpy module giving your data as a paramter:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,5])
data_without_nan = np.nan_to_num(data)
```

prints:

```
array([1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 5.])
```

In your example:

```
import numpy as np
val = np.nan_to_num(setTo.ravel())
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried `val = np.nan_to_num(setTo.ravel())` but I still seem to be getting: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').`

Comment: I'm also not sure if it's due to a NaN value or possibly a value too large. I don't seem to see any NaN in the actual data

Comment: You may try to use [pandas replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html): `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)` to replace inf and -inf with 0

Comment: There are more answers which may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for

Comment: Thanks again for your help! So I tried `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)` but still getting the error. I tried some of the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for, `np.isfinite(X)` showed true so that must be the problem!!

Comment: Not sure why it's infinite though, the array just contains numbers like: `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]`

Comment: If `np.isfinite` returns True it means that there are __no__ nan, inf or -inf, so the data is fine. Maybe it contains numbers greater than can fit in `float32`. You can check the max value for `float32` in your system by using [numpy.iinfo](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html): `np.iinfo(np.float32)`.

Comment: Whoops I read that as infinite. I tried                                                 `np.finfo(np.float32)` and got  `precision =   6   resolution = 1.0000000e-06
machep =    -23   eps =        1.1920929e-07
negep =     -24   epsneg =     5.9604645e-08
minexp =   -126   tiny =       1.1754944e-38
maxexp =    128   max =        3.4028235e+38
nexp =        8   min =        -max` could that be why some of my data like `8.76456812459364E+117` be causing the error?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Your `np.info` said that max value can be `3.4028235e+38` - can you use `float64` instead? It's max value is ≈ `1.8 × 10^308` which should handle all your data. Eventually you can divide all your data by some large number, but it may create other problems for you.

Comment: I tried printing both `print(X.dtypes)` `print(y.dtype)` which makes up `rdf.fit(X,y)` and everything was either `float64` or `int64`, yet I still get the error for `float32`

Comment: On what instruction do you get the error exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118137/discussion-between-yjay-and-beniamin-h).